# Tivoli Workload Scheduler Integration with JENKINS

Tags: jenkins, tivoli-work-scheduler

Is it possible to interface Tivoli Workload Scheduler with Jenkins such as to trigger TWS job streams from Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

There's no out-of-the-box jenkins plugin, but there are many IBM Workload Scheduler interfaces that you can leverage to submit the job stream from jenkins:

1. **conman sbs** command line.
   https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGSPN_9.4.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.4/distr/src_ref/awsrgsubmitsched.htm
2. REST APIs,if you are running TWSd 9.3 FP2 or later.
   https://start.wa.ibmserviceengage.com/twsd/
3. Java APIs.
   https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGSPN_9.4.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.4/common/src_dgd/awsddjapi.htm
4. generate a custom event using **sendevent** and create an event rule to handle that event performing a submit.
   https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGSPN_9.4.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.4/distr/src_ref/awsrgeventsend4dyn.htm